# Heroku Docker Deploy build args

Tags: docker, heroku

I am using the Heroku Review Apps feature with Heroku Docker deploys, which is currently working well (each new review app runs a Docker build, and runs the container as expected).

I now have a need to install a private npm module, which means I need a secure npm token available during build time.

I have seen that it is possible to supply these as config parameters inside a heroku.yml file, however that seems to require the secret to be commited to the repository which is not a good option.

Is there a way to use a secret during the build process?

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/build-docker-images-heroku-yml#setting-build-time-environment-variables

I have attempted to use Heroku Enviornment variables but they are not available at build time. I have confirmed that this is correctly available on the review app

heroku.yml

```
build:
  docker:
    web: Dockerfile
```

app.json

```
{
  "name": "redacted",   
  "scripts": { },   
  "stack": "container",
    "addons": [ ],  
    "buildpacks": [ ],  
    "env": {
      "NPM_TOKEN": {
        "required": true
      }
    },  
    "formation": {  
      "web": {  
        "quantity": 1   
      } 
    }   
  }
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No. This is unfortunately not something currently provided by Heroku.
You cannot set secure build-time config vars for docker builds.

Comment: Sadly! Here is the related doc: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/build-docker-images-heroku-yml#setting-build-time-environment-variables